# how to call a function after another function with ajax call completes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Here are two functions in javascript:

```
function func1() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
      ...
    });
  }, 120000);
}

function func2() {
  // do something
}
```

Is there a way to execute func2 after func1 returns?

Here I don't want to pass func2 into func1 as a callback, because func2 is for testing purpose.

Comment: Learn javascript promises

Answer (score 0):

just call after `success` or `error`

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(resp) {
    func2();
  }
  error: function(resp) {
    func2();
  }
});
```